# Instagram API for posting to relationship not working

Tags: ajax, api, post, instagram

I have tried for a day now so I will post - does anyone know why the following code for posting follow relationship using Instagram API wont work?

```
    $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<user-id>/relationship?access_token=' + instagramaccesstoken,
            data: JSON.stringify({ "action": "unfollow" }),
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#loading").show();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $("#loading").hide();
            }
     });
```

Comment: try sending the access_token in the `data` json, not in URL param, what response are u getting, u may have to do POST on server side, if not u may get cross-origin errors

Answer (score -3):

If you replace the `<user-id>` placeholder in your URL with a real user ID, then it will work.